# Where did Katniss get another rope?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hunger-games

During the *The Hunger Games* (2012), We see Katniss Everdeen in a tree tied up by a rope because she was sleeping.

She woke up to a bush fire raging towards her, so as a result, she went and untied her rope, dropped to the ground and ran off without the rope.

Later, the very next night, she had yet another rope of exactly the same colour. Each backpack includes only one rope to add to the challenge of survival. There was no evidence she went a robbed another tribute, I may have missed something, if I have, I want to know.

Here is some of the source: *The group received a spile as their first gift, and the awl was used to puncture a .... In The Hunger Games film, Katniss finds a coil of rope in the backpack*

I wasn't able to access the source itself due to filters installed in the computer, but the source is located in this [link](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Tools_and_Gear).

As we read here, Katniss found *a* coil of rope, nothing suggests there she had more than one rope.

**So where did she get the second rope from?**

Comment: What is your evidence that each backpack only contains one rope? The books?

Comment: I wasn't able to access the page because of school computer filters, but this is the source: www.thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Tools_and_Gear

Comment: Not everything is shown on camera, especially if the plot doesn't hinge on it. Similarly, we didn't see anyone take any toilet breaks, though the game lasted long enough for everyone to have needed one at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a dog kibble under my sofa.  This doesn't mean that there aren't more...

According to the [Backpack wiki](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Backpack), backpacks don't explicitly contain ropes (unless you can it a 'tool'):

> Backpacks may include:
>   ◾Matches
>   ◾Weapons
>   ◾Blankets or sleeping bags
>   ◾Extra clothing
>   ◾Wire
>   ◾Nets
>   ◾Tools and gear
>   ◾Food and water
>   ◾First aid kits
>   ◾ Medicine

So, she could have more than one rope laying loose at the Cornucopia and picked them up off-camera (the wiki shows that ropes were laying around in the open as well as being the contents of individual backpacks.

I'd imagine that in terms of film-making, having to film a scene where Katniss goes back to find another rope after she lost the first one would result in a loss of story momentum.

Comment: Also - one very long rope would be unwieldy trying to tie herself while up there, with limited mobility, with all that extra length.  She cuts a piece long enough for her needs off the longer, original rope.

Comment: Umm. It's a movie. I'm pretty sure that getting absolutely everything true to life and explainable in real world terms isn't going to happen if it wasn't novelized by Alan Dean Foster.

Comment: Just another alternative for people who get obsessed by the pedantics of it.  "There's no proof of two ropes!"  "There's proof of a knife, and a rope, so, technically, two are not needed."  There's a legion of people out there who think finding non-existent errors is some badge of intelligence or cleverness.